# Pipeline Level Access Control for Service Connection in Azure DevOps - Classic Editor Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, serviceconnection, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have a SSH service connection created in Azure DevOps. My account has  enabled *'New service connections experience'* preview feature and able to see new security features for service connections. It appears that we can enable security so that certain YAML pipeline(s) are able to use service connection.However, I do not see similar feature for Classic Editor pipeline.Can I get some suggestions on how I can achieve something similar for Classic Editor?

Example : Below details are under same ADO organization and project with same level of user(user/admin/reader) level access

Service Connection name : test-ssh-connection
Classic Editor Pipelines Created: 
1) pipeline1 - this can use service connection 
2) pipeline2 - we want to restrict service connection so that this pipeline is not able to use service connection.

Comment: Hello Lance, Thank you for your answer. I requested for this feature via User Voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It appears that we can enable security so that certain YAML
> pipeline(s) are able to use service connection.However, I do not see
> similar feature for Classic Editor pipeline.Can I get some suggestions
> on how I can achieve something similar for Classic Editor?

Sorry but a similar experience for Classic pipeline is **not supported** for now. Just as [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) states, [pipeline permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-permissions) are only for Yaml pipelines while [user permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#user-permissions) are for Classic pipelines.

For Classic pipelines, if the account someone uses to sign in Web portal doesn't have the user permission, then the pipeline created by him can't access the service connection:

[image]

Though what you want is not supported, I agree with you that it would be better if the pipeline permissions feature can support Classic pipelines. So my suggestion is to add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps!

[image]